# Anonymity of Bitcoin

Tags: anonymity, tor, bitcoin

I just asked myself that when you have bitcoin network, which is as we know "pseudo" anonym. Because of the transaction logs of the network (which are afaik endless), it seems that transactions are traceable. But my question is how traceable am i when i am using a bitcoin client with something like tor or other networks like i2p or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there are a few possibilities here. First of all when you are purchassing something with Bitcoin, you have to send that "something" to your house or email address. If it's non-physical you might be able to stay anonymous if you create your account behind Tor.

There are also a number of services that are speciliazed in making it harder to follow transactions. What they do is:

- you pay them on address X which is created ad hoc
- they use address Y to pay you on a new address, minus some transaction fees for their service
- looking at your account someone can still see you sent money to a certain address of such a service, but they can't trace to where the service sent your money off to (which is your secret wallet).

This is not foolproof though as someone might try to figure out all addresses and cross-reference the amounts and wallet addresses.